# A option of night mode in an app which automatically reduces the screen brightness. Will it workout using some php or html or css code?

Tags: php, html, css

This code is basic one which changes the background to black one.

**PHP CODE**

```
if ($res160[0] == "1") {
    echo "<script>$('body').css('background-color', 'black'); $('body').css('color', 'white');</script>";
}
```

How do I write a code to reduce the brightness?

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS property `filter` which is used to reduce the brightness.

```
filter: brightness(50%);
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by changing the brightness of the container(body or div) something like this.

```js
var x = $("#myRange");

$("body").css({
  "opacity": x.val()
});

x.on("change mousemove", function() {
  $("#contents").css({
    "filter": "brightness(" + $(this).val() * 100 + "%)"
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Choose Light Level<br>
<input id='myRange' type="range" min="0.3" max="1" step="0.1" value=1><br> dark -> light

<div id="contents">
  <div style="">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nightlife/Dummy-Text">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/Dummy-Text">
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: red;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nightlife/Dummy-Text">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/Dummy-Text">
  </div>
</div>
```